# Why can a enum have a package-private constructor?

Tags: java, enums, package-private

Since an enum constructor can only be invoked by its constants, why is it then allowed to be package-private?

Comment: to allow to save a bit on code space and to avoid needless verbosity (like interfaces don't need `public abstract` before every method)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: It's not like interfaces. Interface methods are *always* `public abstract`. Making the modifiers explicit is allowed, but there's no way to change them.

Comment: @RyanStewart there's also no way to call a enum constructor yourself so it becomes logically private and allowing package private allows saving those few chars

Comment: I stand corrected: "If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of an enum type, the constructor is private." -- [JLS 8.8.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.3). It seems the java tutorial is incorrect or at least misleading.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The constructor actually isn't package-private... it's implicitly `private` the way interface methods are implicitly `public` even if you don't add the keyword.

The relevant section of the JLS ([§8.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3)) states:

> If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of a normal class, the constructor has default access.
>
> If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of an enum type, the constructor is `private`.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the constructor of an enum type (§8.9) is declared `public` or `protected`.

Comment: citation: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.3

Comment: Updated link for citation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3

Answer (score 5):

It's a quirk of the language: enum constructors are implicitly private.

Interestingly, if you declare a package-visible enum constructor, like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A(0),
    B(1);

    private final int i;

    MyEnum(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

you can't refer to it from another class in the package. If you try, you get the compiler error:

> Cannot instantiate the type MyEnum

Comment: Apparently you can try this with enum being static nested class or in a method of the enum. Yes, compilation fails with said error.

Comment: "if you declare a package-visible enum constructor"...but actually there is no way to do that.

Comment: @raghavsood33 yes you can. See the compilable code I added to my answer that demonstrates a package-visible constructor.

Comment: The constructor in your code is not package-private; it is private. It just lacks an explicit `private` keyword. That would only make it package-private if it were a class, but it is an enum, not a class.