# Should enum constructor be marked as private?

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I prepare to scjp exam by book readind.

quote from book:

```
A constructor in an enum class can only be specified as private.
```

but I wrote code for test:

```
enum En{
    VAL_1;
    En(){
        System.out.println("123");
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
    }
}
```

this code works for me.

Is it book bug or compiler bug ?

P.S. with  protected and public access modifiers code doesn't work

Comment: `enum` object is created by `enum` itself. You can't create it's object from outside hence there is no meaning of changing the visibility if the constructor other than `private`. You can change it but no meaning of it at all but `public` and `protected` are not allowed.

Comment: @Braj why does for package visible and for protected use difference politics ?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747948/why-can-a-enum-have-a-package-private-constructor

Comment: @Katona interesting - thanks

Comment: Read it here [Java Language Specification - Enum Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation is stated that enum constructor must be package-private or private.

[Enum tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: **If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of an enum type, the constructor is private** please add it to answer