# Executing action depending on enum value

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to retrieving a value depending on the enum value.
Basically, let's say I have the following enum:

```
    private enum Auth{

    KEY, PASSWORD, MAIL;    

    public String get(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

By doing Auth.KEY.get() it would return "mykey", while Auth.MAIL.get() would return "mymail"
I googled a bit but I couldn't find an answer, I didn't try anything before because I totally hadn't an idea on how I could start.

Comment: Just google for "Java enum tutorial", click on the first link, and read.

Comment: enums can have a constructor and its own fields.... consider that too please

Comment: I would like to do this without a constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add a function to enums in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457076/can-i-add-a-function-to-enums-in-java)

Comment: @RubenOktay you can do it with an abstract method overridden in each enum, or your get() method could use a switch statement to test the value of `this`, but a field and a constructor is way simpler. Why wouldn't you use that?

Comment: Well, i cannot use a constructor as the string will be updated often..

Comment: That's probably a bad idea, but anyway, I don't see how that prevents you from using a constructor. To the contrary. If the string s updated, you *need* a field to contain the new value, and you thus need a constructor to initialize the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I strongly advise not to use the following mechanism for getting something simple like a hardcoded `String` from an enum value and rather use it for associating particular behavior like in `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`, this is how it can be achieved:

```
private enum Auth {

    KEY {
        public String get() {
            return "mykey";
        } 
    },

    PASSWORD {
        public String get() {
            return "mypassword";
        } 
    },

    MAIL {
        public String get() {
            return "mymail";
        } 
    };

    public abstract String get();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a field and constructor, as explained in the [java-docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Example code:

```
enum Auth {

    KEY("myKey"), PASSWORD("myPass"), MAIL("myMail");    

    private final String identifier;

    Auth(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String get(){
        return identifier;
    }
}
```

Also note, that there is [name()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()) and [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString()) which may be useful: see also [java-enum-why-use-tostring-instead-of-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291076/java-enum-why-use-tostring-instead-of-name)

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Auth{
private enum Auth{
String value;
KEY("mykey"), PASSWORD("mypassword"),    MAIL(mymail");    

Auth(String value){
thia.value=value;
}
public String get(){
    return value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a string which holds the name of of enum and a constructor which sets it. Then get method returns the name as below.

```
 private enum Auth{

    KEY, PASSWORD, MAIL;    
    string name;
    public Auth(string nm) {
      name = nm;
    }
    public String get(){
        return name;
    }
 }
```